# deploying Java web application in exploded directory outside the Tomcat server, using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, tomcat5.5

I have been using IntelliJ IDE (version 5.1) with Tomcat server (version 5.5) to build my Java web applications. I'm now trying to migrate my project to Eclipse IDE.

When I run my web application from IntelliJ IDE, it creates a *exploded* directory inside my web application project folder and then starts the server and runs the web app. (i.e. no WAR files and no copy to *tomcat\webapps* folder).

But in Eclipse IDE, it usually deploys the web app inside Tomcat's *webapps* folder.

Is there any way to deploy web applications to a *exploded* directory outside the Tomcat server, from Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is pretty neat Eclipse plug-ins you can install that will allow you to do that.

Have a look at [Plug-in](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html), [tutorial](http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/distrubutedSite/platoAcadiau_ca/EclipseAndTomcatTutorial/index.htm) and [from Sysdeo](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ectom/).

Sysdeo is the one that both Apache and IBM suggests.

There are actually quite a bunch of these plug-ins from different vendors.

The trick is to find the one that best suits your needs.

Hope this helps.